# Display rest of layout fields on button click on same View

Tags: android, android-layout

I have layout containing 30 fields ( using editbox, spinners, buttons etc)
but it looks too weird with crowded elements. ( scroll view is also longer)
So i decided to keep 1 more button, so firstly 15 fields will display and 1 "More" button below,now i want to display rest of fields onClick "more" button on  same layout  ( below that  15 fields). How to do this, thanks in advance

Comment: On load of the activity, hide the second half of the elements, using, object.setVisibility(View.GONE). Then on the click of button "More" show them using, object.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE). This should work. By object i mean, textview, edittext and so on...

Comment: Very helpful Vamsi, This works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to make a parent view with two main relative layouts. First relative layout for all the content you want to show at first time. Make this layout visibility `View.VISIBLE`. Second relative layout for all the content you want to show on click event. Make this layout visibility `View.INVISIBLE`.
On button click event make second relative layout visible by setting `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

Don't forget the invisible the layout in the end. Otherwise it will be visible throughout the app session.

You can also set this property in your xml too. There is a `android:visibility="visible"` tag in every view.

This approach will help you in management because by setting a single view visibility you can manage your all view. Happy Coding!!

Comment: its Done , now adding animation (dropdown effect) for it  :)